# htaccess 301 redirect everything except /admin

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have been scratching my head for almost half an hour already because of this. I don't know what I am doing wrong, might just be under my nose, but i just cant see it. Here's what I have on my `.htaccess`

```
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

When I access `example.com/admin`, i am still redirected to `newsite.com/admin`.
Can anyone please advise? Thanks!

UPDATE: This is my everything that I have on mod_rewrite currently:

```
  RewriteRule ^googleabcdef12345.html - [L] 
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sample1\.no$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newsample1.no/$1 [L,R=301]

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example\.com$ [NC]
  #RewriteRule admin - [S=1]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

It is a drupal website btw. I tried QUERY_STRING instead of REQUEST_URI but no luck still.

Comment: Those rules work fine for me. Are you sure you cleared your browser's cache? or some other caching issue?

Comment: Everytime I test this, I use chrome's incognito mode so there should be no problem with my browser's cache. I still haven't solve this :(

Comment: even trying `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]` alone does not exclude `/admin` sad :(

Comment: And these are the only rules you have?

Comment: Hi Jon Lin, thanks for taking the time to respond. I have updated my post

Comment: Actually, I tried simple tests on a fresh drupal install using ` RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin [NC]` but the "!" seem to not work as a negation syntax.